# Async function don't run as expected

Tags: javascript, async-await

I do have a problem with my asnyc functions, because they are not running one after another.
That is my code:

```
async function main() {
  async function func() {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var result_amount = await calc(array[i]);
      if (result_amount > amount_start * 0.5) {
        console.log(
          "i: ",
          i,
          "Route: ",
          array[i][6],
          "amount_start: ",
          amount_start,
          "amount: ",
          result_amount
        );
      }
    }
  }

  const POLLING_INTERVAL = process.env.POLLING_INTERVAL || 1000; 
  Monitor = setInterval(async () => {
    await func();
  }, POLLING_INTERVAL);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

So there I am calling calc with the i-th element of my `array`.
Lets say array has length 10. Then the code does not execute `i = 0`, then `i = 1`, then `i = 2` ando so an, instead it is doing like `i = 0`, then `i = 1`, but then again `i = 0`.
Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

Thank you!

Comment: sounds like your interval is not waiting long enough? Maybe you should be restart the poll after all the async calls have been made.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: `async function func() { for (...) {...} setTimeout(func, POLLING_INTERVAL);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you are not handling the promise correctly inside setInterval.
You need to "promisify" the setInterval method like so (keep in mind, I did not test this out but it should work):

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setInterval(async function() {
      await func()
      resolve();
    }, POLLING_INTERVAL)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code mocking some of data and for me it looks like it is going through all array.

I assume that there is some issue with one of the functions you have defined (probably **calc()** which has some timeout inside)